# Вывод массива по выбраному критерию php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица, в которой поле `alias` по которому сортируется вывод. Нужно в трех местах вывести записи по **конкретному** `alias`, дабы три раза запрос не делать, как сделать одним?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$array=array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $array[$row['alias']][] = $row;
}
```

а дальше не знаю как вывести записи по `alias`

Comment: так в чем проблема? в `$array` уже есть все записи, разбитые по `alias`, осталось их вывести: `foreach ($array[$YOUR_ALIAS] as $row) {...}`. Перед циклом не мешала бы проверка на наличие нужного вам `$YOUR_ALIAS`

Comment: спасибо сработало)

Comment: @BOPOH, пожалуйста, перенесите ваш комментарий в ответ. Возможно ваше решение поможет кому-то еще.

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев*

В `$array` уже есть все записи, разбитые по `alias`, осталось их вывести:

```
if(isset($YOUR_ALIAS)) {
  foreach ($array[$YOUR_ALIAS] as $row) {
    ...
  }
}
```